# session problem with IE8 in php

Tags: php

I have a simple code to check counter.

```
     session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['footerimg']) || empty($_SESSION['footerimg']) ){
         $_SESSION['footerimg']='sunset.jpg';
        echo $_SESSION['footerimg'];
      }
```

But all time this is printing "sinsut.jpg" when is page is loading my session is being destroy.
This is running well in FF but problem happeninig with IE and chrome.

Answer (score 2):

This is most definitely because IE8 doesn't accept cookies from `localhost`. Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134290/cookies-on-localhost-with-explicit-domain).

Comment: Well, otherwise I don't know what could be the cause. Maybe you should update the question and post some details about how your development environment is set up?