# Zend Framework 1.10: Cookies aren't stored

Tags: php, zend-framework, cookies, zend-http-client

I'm trying to with Cookies and Zend Framework 1.10. This is my code:

```
$zendCookie = new Zend_Http_Cookie('foo', 'bar', 'localhost', time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 30);

$client = new Zend_Http_Client();
$client->setCookie($zendCookie);
```

But the cookies aren't stored. I checked it with Firecookie Firefox's extension.
What's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem even using php's setcookie(), but setting domain field to empty works. Although Zend_Http_Cookie() will throw an exception if domain field is left empty.

Cookie will not work with my localhost's virtualhost

```
setcookie ( 'FOO', 'cookie content', 0, '/', 'myProjectSiteVHost', true, true);
```

Setting domain field to empty - Cookie stored!

```
setcookie ( 'FOO', 'cookie content', 0, '/', '', true, true);
```

Docs: [setcookie()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php)

Answer (score 0):

Localhost does some weird stuff with cookies.

I would setup a vhost with a psuedo server name and make this an entry in your hosts file and point it to `127.0.0.1`

IE:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName test.dev
    #(other required / normal items here)
</VirtualHost>
```

Then in your /etc/hosts  (or C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts) You would add:

```
127.0.0.1        test.dev
```

Then you can access the application locally by calling test.dev   and you would use that in place of "localhost" for the cookies and it should not mess with the cookies like localhost does. You can find a bit more information on what I am talking about with the localhost cookies [here](http://www.aeonity.com/frost/php-setcookie-localhost-apache).

Answer (score 0):

[Cookies on localhost with explicit domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134290/cookies-on-localhost-with-explicit-domain)

I think the problem is because the full-stop/period is missing before the domain name i.e. ".domain.com" only some browsers will except the domain without the leading dot.