# Sinatra - response.set_cookie doesn't work

Tags: ruby, cookies, set, sinatra

I need to use a cookie for my Sinatra application. If I use the simpliest method is works:

```
response.set_cookie('my_cookie', 'value_of_cookie')
```

but I need some options such as domain and expire date so I try this:

```
response.set_cookie("my_cookie", {:value => 'value_of_cookie', :domain => myDomain, :path => myPath, :expires => Date.new})
```

does not work. No cookie is made. I need this so much....

Please help... thanks!

Comment: How are you determining that no cookie is made? Browser cookie store? Later use in your application? Reading the traffic on the wire with wireshark? Does the `:expire => Date.new` mean the cookie should expire "this very instant"?

Comment: I use a cookie addon in Firefox.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The documentation on http://sinatra-book.gittr.com/#cookies says to use the set_cookie helper, but in newer versions of Sinatra (at least from 1.2.0+ and possibly earlier), you should use response.set_cookie to set cookies.

```
response.set_cookie("my_cookie", :value => "value_of_cookie",
                    :domain => myDomain,
                    :path => myPath,
                    :expires => Date.new(2020,1,1))
cookie = request.cookies["my_cookie"]
```

**SUMMARY**

don't set `localhost` as a domain for your cookies because you need to set it to "" or FALSE

Comment: set_cookie is not a helper anymore. Now it's response.set_cookie(). This should be correct but does not work: http://www.gittr.com/index.php/archive/sinatra-cookie-handling-in-0-9-4/

Comment: This works: response.set_cookie('my_cookie', { :value => 'abc', :path => request.path, :expires => Time.now + (60 * 60 * 24 * 30) }). It expires after a month. But why the :domain parameter doesn't work. :domain => request.host would be 'localhost' in my case. If I add that parameter it does not work.... but why?

Comment: `request.path` will not return a domain!!! for me works perfect for `response.set_cookie("my_cookie", :value => "1234", :domain => ".smackaho.st")`

Comment: Yes my mistake with request.path... I know. But why doesn't request.host work?

Comment: try `request.env['SERVER_NAME']` or `request.env['HTTP_HOST']`

Comment: Doesn't work unfortunately... Maybe doesn't work with localhost?

Comment: what does it return? are you testing it on localhost?

Comment: Yes, on localhost. If I use request.env['SERVER_NAME'] or request.env['HTTP_HOST'] or  request.host the cookie is not created.

Comment: Oh :) the reason is your localhost :). You can't set domain as localhost. Try run this url: http://test.smackaho.st:4567 just change port to what you are running your application

Comment: Actually out of localhost even `request.host` will works perfect :)

Comment: read this about setting `localhost` as a domain for cookie: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134290/cookies-on-localhost-with-explicit-domain `when working on localhost (!) the cookie-domain must be set to "" or NULL or FALSE instead of "localhost"`

Comment: I tested on some free domain of mine. Indeed.... it was because of localhost :)). So much struggle for this one. Thanks for your time :). I hope this will be useful for others, too.