# Sinatra cookies: how to set the validity date?

Tags: ruby, web-applications, cookies, sinatra

I use the [Sinatra:Contrib](http://www.sinatrarb.com/contrib/cookies.html) gem to set a cookie.

```
cookies[:something] = 'foobar'
```

But in firebug I saw that it's only valid until the end of the session.

How can I manually set the expiration date of the cookie?

Comment: This SO question may helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078091/sinatra-response-set-cookie-doesnt-work

Comment: https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra-contrib/issues/59