# How to set and read raw cookie in Ruby/Sinatra

Tags: ruby, cookies, session-cookies

I have a bunch of domains such as store.example.com, user.example.com, intranet.example.com and each one can read cookies. However, I have a Sinatra app that is writing the cookies by doing something like `session[:field] = value`

When I inspect the cookie, I get something like this: `BAh7CUkiD3Nlc3Npb25faWQGOgZFVEkiRTcwNmUwYTU1MjBmMzUyMTZiYzQ0%0ANjZhZDBkOGFmNmFhN2M3OGIxZTM3NGNjMDZiYmRkNDE2MmVlMDU2MWY2MTQG%0AOwBGSSIJY3NyZgY7AEZJIiVkMWUyYzI0NmEwZThiNjVhM2FlZGJjNWFhMzlk%0AYzc0YQY7AEZJIg10cmFja2luZwY7AEZ7B0kiFEhUVFBfVVNFUl9BR0VOVAY7%0AAFRJIi0xZDQ3MmI3NDZiMjFhNmJlNmYyMmUxMGU1MzI3N2Q5MmVlYmQ1N2Qx%0ABjsARkkiGUhUVFBfQUNDRVBUX0xBTkdVQUdFBjsAVEkiLTY2ZWFlOTcxNDky%0AOTM4YzJkY2MyZmIxZGRjOGQ3ZWMzMTk2MDM3ZGEGOwBGSSIQdXNlcl9zZWNy%0AZXQGOwBGSSIlMjg3NjdkMGVmNmZlOGUwMDIxMDRmODhiZDcwZTI1OTYGOwBU%0A--e8ca14be9bbe63226fd2d6e0f8c0b3946cc66fd0` which appears to be both base64 encoded and encrypted.

My question is how can I write a 'raw' cookie that can be easily read by all subdomains trying to consume it? It doesn't need to be encrypted and/or encoded.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use Sinatra Cookies http://www.sinatrarb.com/contrib/cookies.html

```
require "sinatra/cookies"
cookies[:something] = 'foobar'
```

You can also read raw cookies in the request object:

```
request.cookies
```

As described in [Accessing the Request Object](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Accessing%20the%20Request%20Object)

There is also the `set_cookie` method of the response object

```
response.set_cookie("my_cookie", :value => "value_of_cookie",
                    :domain => myDomain,
                    :path => myPath,
                    :expires => Date.new(2020,1,1))
```

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/5078196/156746
- http://craig-russell.co.uk/2013/01/31/persistent-cookies-sinatra.html#.U9KVFIBdWUA