# Creating a JavaScript cookie on a domain and reading it across sub domains

Tags: javascript, cookies

Below is a JavaScript cookie that is written on the user's computer for 12 months.

After we set the cookie on our main domain such as `example.com`, should the user visit a subdomain like `test.example.com`, we need to continue to identify the activity of the user across our "test" subdomain.

But with the current code, as soon as they leave `www.example.com` and visit `test.example.com`, they are no longer flagged as "HelloWorld".

Would anyone be able to help with my code to allow the cookie to be read across subdomains?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var cookieName = 'HelloWorld';
  var cookieValue = 'HelloWorld';
  var myDate = new Date();
  myDate.setMonth(myDate.getMonth() + 12);
  document.cookie = cookieName +"=" + cookieValue + ";expires=" + myDate;
</script>
```

Answer (score 252, accepted):

Just set the `domain` and `path` attributes on your cookie, like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var cookieName = 'HelloWorld';
var cookieValue = 'HelloWorld';
var myDate = new Date();
myDate.setMonth(myDate.getMonth() + 12);
document.cookie = cookieName +"=" + cookieValue + ";expires=" + myDate 
                  + ";domain=.example.com;path=/";
</script>
```

Comment: I'm trying to do this in localhost and I cannot change path

Comment: @Enve - Browsers treat localhost cookies a bit differently than other cookies.  Or rather, they treat all cookies in a way that makes working with _localhost_ difficult.  For instance, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134290/cookies-on-localhost-with-explicit-domain.  I suggest editing your `hosts` file and aliasing something like `myserver.local` to `127.0.0.1`.  Then you can use that to access your local server (and when setting cookies), and hopefully everything should work.

Comment: All cookie values you create & retrieve must be string values. Strings can contain characters that can upset the local storage when trying to retrieve them. One thing I would suggest is using the global `encodeURI()` & `decodeURI()` methods for the cookie name & value to handle any conversion that would need to take place. i.e. `document.cookie = encodeURI(cookieName) +"=" + encodeURI(cookieValue)`.

Comment: If your server-side code is written in C#, Rick Strahl provides a method for getting the base domain, e.g. example.com, from the domain at https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/Apr/24/Getting-a-base-Domain-from-a-Domain

Comment: Unfortunately `sub.example.com` cannot set cookie for `.example.com` using javascript

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me. If I do this, followed by `console.log(document.cookes);` gives me a null return. Also nothing showing in browser storage.

Answer (score 45):

You want:

```
document.cookie = cookieName +"=" + cookieValue + ";domain=.example.com;path=/;expires=" + myDate;
```

As per the [RFC 2109](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2109.txt), to have a cookie available to all subdomains, you must put a `.` in front of your domain.

Setting the path=/ will have the cookie be available within the entire specified domain(aka `.example.com`).

Comment: FWIW - I think you need to remove the "path=expires=" piece and set it to "expires=".

Comment: As per the newer [RFC 6265](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6265) it's no longer necessary to include the `.` in front of the domain.

Answer (score 10):

Here is a working example :

```
document.cookie = "testCookie=cookieval; domain=." + 
location.hostname.split('.').reverse()[1] + "." + 
location.hostname.split('.').reverse()[0] + "; path=/"
```

This is a generic solution that takes the root domain from the location object and sets the cookie.  The reversing is because you don't know how many subdomains you have if any.

Comment: This will not work if there is second level hierarchy of domain extension e.g. .co.in

Answer (score 4):

You can also use the [Cookies API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Work_with_the_Cookies_API) and do:

```
browser.cookies.set({
  url: 'example.com',
  name: 'HelloWorld',
  value: 'HelloWorld',
  expirationDate: myDate
}
```

[MDN `Set()` Method Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/cookies/set)

Comment: The link is broken

Comment: It looks like the documentation was moved. Thanks for the heads up @CodingYourLife!

Comment: This solution only applies to browser extensions, not to javascript running in the context of a page.