# Save Cookies, Then Open Link in New Tab

Tags: javascript, cookies

I have some javascript code that saves a cookie. However, if after saving the cookie, the user opens a new tab, it appears that the cookie is not saved. The new tab is on the same domain.

Here is my cookie setting/getting code:

```
function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays)
{
    var exdate=new Date();
    exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
    var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
    document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;
}

function getCookie(c_name)
{
    var i,x,y,ARRcookies=document.cookie.split(";");
    for (i=0;i<ARRcookies.length;i++) {
        x=ARRcookies[i].substr(0,ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
        y=ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=")+1);
        x=x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
        if (x==c_name) {
            return unescape(y);
        }
    }
}
```

If some javascript calls `setCookie('mycookie', 1)` and then the user clicks on a link where the `_target` is set to `_blank`, the cookie does not load in the new tab. So `getCookie('mycookie')` will not return `1`.

What is the problem here?

Comment: are these 2 pages on different domains?

Comment: yup, clarified it above.

Comment: Sorry, I meant they are on the same domains, not different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I figured it out.

I was setting the cookie on one subdirectory and then reading it on another. So I was setting the cookie on `www.example.com/foo/` then loading a new tab on `www.example.com/bar/` and the cookie was no longer there.  I think the setCookie function above does not handle this properly. My solution was to use a [more robust cookie library](http://code.google.com/p/cookies/).

Answer (score 0):

This could be a security issue, specially if the two pages are on different domains/sub-domains

Read this [Question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5671451/creating-a-javascript-cookie-on-a-domain-and-reading-it-across-sub-domains) and try to implement

Comment: also, a very good read if you want to understand it in detail

http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html