# Mobile redirect and full site to subdomains

Tags: javascript, jquery, redirect, mobile

After i finished the mobile version of my website i used the https://github.com/sebarmeli/JS-Redirection-Mobile-Site to make the redirection to mobile site and also the redirection to the full site. Also i am using the cookie function to save the state for 1 hour using the code bellow:

```
  <script>
                 SA.redirection_mobile ({
                noredirection_param : "noredirection", 
                mobile_prefix : "m", 
                cookie_hours : "1"
                });
            </script>
```

The problem that i have is that i use subdomains in my site and when i came back to full site if i click to a link for example news.site.com/cat1/news1 or video.site.com/video1 the redirection goes back to mobile site because cookie is created for www.site.com site the redirection is www.site.com/noredirection=true.

Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is pretty easy to fix if you set the cookie yourself without the www. Setting the domain for the cookie as .site.com would allow for any subdomain.[Take a look at this stack answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5671451/creating-a-javascript-cookie-on-a-domain-and-reading-it-across-sub-domains) 
You might be able to modify the script your using, or just setting the cookie manually.