# Safari browser not handling cookie - PHP

Tags: php, safari

I am stuck on this problem for the last two days,
I Have the following code in my main "login.php" file
Which is running in all browsers without any problem, but not in "Safari".

```
 if(isset($_SESSION["del_log"]) && !empty($_SESSION["del_log"]) && isset($_SESSION["user_type"]) && !empty($deal_type)){

            $expire=time()+60*60*24*365;
            setcookie("del_log",$_SESSION["del_log"], $expire, '/');
            setcookie("user_type", $_SESSION["user_type"], $expire, '/');

    echo "<script>window.location.href=\"http://www.sample.com/foldername/index.php\"</script>";
        }
```

i am checking these cookies in ".../foldername/index.php" file as:

```
 if (isset($_COOKIE["del_log"]) && !empty($_COOKIE["del_log"])){
     $log=$_COOKIE["del_log"];
     $user_type=$_COOKIE["user_type"];
 }else{
     echo "<script>window.location.href=\"http://www.sample.com/\"</script>";
 }
```

Comment: Does it set cookie and doesn't read or doesn't set at all?

Comment: it not setting the cookies...

Answer (score 3):

Encounter this issue before. The session's cookie path ( http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php ) must have a trailing slash in order to work. Safari specific.

See my another question's answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15131791/188331

Comment: Spent considerable time on this problem myself. This answer is correct, but I want to add the problem is not-only Safari-specific for me; Chrome on iOS behaved the same way.

Comment: Chrome on iOS is  basically safari. no different. just a different skin.

Comment: @CalebPrenger how do you come out with this conclusion? Terribly wrong.

Comment: Because apple doesn't allow other browsers on their iOS platform. If you go to a browser detection script online, it will return as safari.

Comment: That's another reason chrome on iOS still will not support push api because safari does not yet support it.