# $_COOKIE not working in Safari iOS

Tags: php, ios, wordpress, cookies, safari

When using the following snippet in Chrome and FF it works fine. But iOS and Safari will not get the cookie.

```
<?php $current_gemeente = $_COOKIE["Gemeente"]; ?>
```

I've confirmed the cookie is been placed on developer tools and connecting a iPhone and test with Safari on a Mac. When using a simple W3Schools javascript function to read the cookie it works perfectly fine.

I've confirmed that the path is correctly "/".

If I could I would just get the cookie with Javascript but I need the cookie value for a WordPress query.

Comment: looks like duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15968640/safari-browser-not-handling-cookie-php

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42731886/4248328

Comment: @ViktarPryshchepa I've read that one but mine do have the path given.

Comment: @AlivetoDie I am hosting at a similiar party with optimized WordPress servers so I will check that out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that Safari on mac and iOS have trouble reading the cooking the way I tried above. With the hosting party we have turned every form of caching off and didn't resolve anything.

The code will be rewritten to sessions instead of cookies.