# Cookies across sub-domains

Tags: javascript, cookies

I have two subdomains  foo.example.com and bar.example.com, I am setting javascript cookies on the foo.example.com, but not able access it on bar.example.com, please suggest a way to access the cookie created on the foo.example.com on bar.example.com

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a JavaScript cookie on a domain and reading it across sub domains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5671451/creating-a-javascript-cookie-on-a-domain-and-reading-it-across-sub-domains)

Answer (score 0):

In php I set a persistent cookie to do something similar, if it can be accessed from separate browsing sessions it can be accessed cross-domain i'd imagine.

I have "borrowed" this javascript from @pete because I'm not a JS expert, and barely even a novice, but I think something along these lines could work, set a cookie to expire after a year or other time period, as opposed to when browser session closes or the page has been left.

You'll need to do some messing about with it but hey, that's the fun part!

```
// Build the expiration date string:
var expiration_date = new Date();
var cookie_string = '';
expiration_date.setFullYear(expiration_date.getFullYear() + 1);
// Build the set-cookie string:
cookie_string = "test_cookies=true; path=/; expires=" + 
expiration_date.toUTCString();
// Create or update the cookie: 
document.cookie = cookie_string;
```