# Create a shared authentication cookie in React

Tags: reactjs

I have the following case: I have two restful APIs built in ASP.NET Core, one specific for user authentication, and the other that performs operations, to say the least, student enrollment.

The idea I have is that each API is consumed by a different site, that is, an API is consumed by a React site that manages users and the other by another site that performs registration operations.

So when a user authenticates, the intention is for the React site to create an authentication cookie that can be shared with the license plate site.

Currently I know how to do it with ASP.NET Core MVC, since .net has a configuration mechanism to share cookies between various applications.

But I would like to do this with React, is there a way to do it safely?
I thank you for your great help!

Comment: you might find this question useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5671451/creating-a-javascript-cookie-on-a-domain-and-reading-it-across-sub-domains

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating a JavaScript cookie on a domain and reading it across sub domains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5671451/creating-a-javascript-cookie-on-a-domain-and-reading-it-across-sub-domains)

Comment: Thank you very much lucasreta, in large part, what I would be missing to know how to protect my cookie on the client side, because I understand that when a cookie is created on the server it can be configured so that it is not accessed on the client, HttpOnly = true.
But in this case, since the site would only be built on the client side, then they are created in that environment.