# asp.net can only login in firefox

Tags: asp.net, authentication

in my asp.net website i can only login in Firefox but not in chrome, internet explorer or safari.

here is my code :

```
    string userName = LoginUserName.Text;
    string password = LoginPassword.Text;

        if (Page.IsValid)
    {
        if (Membership.ValidateUser(userName, password))
        {
            if (RemeberMe.Checked == true)
            {
                Response.Redirect("~/Home.aspx");
            }
        }
    }
```

here is the login table :

```
        <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Label Text="Email:" AssociatedControlID="LoginUserName" runat="server" 
                    id="LoginUserNamelabel" CssClass="label"></asp:Label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="LoginUserName" runat="server" Width="250px" CssClass="textbox"/>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator id="LoginEmailRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="LoginUserName"
                    ErrorMessage="Email is required" ToolTip="Email is required"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Label Text="Password:" AssociatedControlID="LoginPassword" runat="server" 
                    ID="LoginPasswordlabel" CssClass="label"></asp:Label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="LoginPassword" runat="server" TextMode="Password" Width="250px" CssClass="textbox" />
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="PassRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="LoginPassword"
                    ErrorMessage="Password is Required" ToolTip="Password is Required"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="RemeberMe" runat="server" Text="Remember me" CssClass="RemeberMe" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><br />
                <asp:Button ID="LoginButton" runat="server" Text="Login" OnClick="autoLogin" CssClass="Button" />
            </td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
            <td><br />
                <asp:Label ID="FailureText" runat="server" EnableViewState="false" Visible="false" CssClass="Lfaluire">
                Wrong Email or Password</asp:Label>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

using the AspNetSqlMembershipProvider.

i am using asp.net 4.0 , what is the problem
thanks

Comment: what membership provider are you using? what does your page look like?

Comment: Is the login button invisible in Chrome and Internet Explorer?

Comment: we need details that are not present here.

Comment: Have you tried if you can logon with [Lynx](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lynx_(web_browser))?

Comment: @Daniel A. White - using the AspNetSqlMembershipProvider and the page looks exactly like in firefox

Comment: @Uwe Keim - no everything looks as it should

Comment: @Daniel A. White - code added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You always validate the username and password, but then only actually redirect if the user has checked the "Remember me" - This looks wrong. Could there be a co-incidence that you ticked the box in some test sessions but not others? ;)

Also you're not actually storing the fact that the user has logged in anywhere, so won't you have problems later with the `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` still being false?

You should be using something like
[FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1f5z1yty.aspx) whether or not the checkbox is checked...

If you want to do the redirect yourself you should be using [FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.setauthcookie.aspx) and then doing the redirect.

**EDIT**: Something like this

```
string userName = LoginUserName.Text;
string password = LoginPassword.Text;

if (Page.IsValid)
{
    if (Membership.ValidateUser(userName, password))
    {
        if (RemeberMe.Checked)
        {
            // Set your own cookie here or something that you will later check for in Page_Load etc
        }

        // Need to tell ASP.NET authentication was successful
        System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userName, True)
        Response.Redirect("~/Home.aspx");
    }
}
```

Comment: yes you are absolutely right i just noticed after posting the question the i wasn't actually logging the user in but more like validating his existence but Mozilla was using from the cache that's why i was able to login. and i use an else so if the check-box isn't checked it still continues. thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are hitting `http://localhost` then most of the browsers won't save the cookie that's being generated by your membership provider.

If this is the case, access it by a name that has a dot in it.  See:
[Cookies on localhost with explicit domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134290/cookies-on-localhost-with-explicit-domain)

Comment: i tried the asp.net ready login component instead of the custom one i am using and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Are cookies enabled in all these browsers? The most common culprit to the out-of-the-box ASP.NET login stuff "not working" is because by default, they have no fallback for when cookies are disabled.

Comment: cookies are enabled in all browsers and i cleared the cookies but no luck