# How do I make my sessions last cross-subdomain in Node.js Express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I want http://mydomain.com to be the same as http://www.mydomain.com

And all other subdomains.

I want sessions and cookies to hold!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Has nothing to do with Express.  It's the settings on the cookie itself that matter.  Set its domain to `.mydomain.com` and you should be fine.

**EDIT**:  The OP wanted more details, so here are the examples from the code.

> ```
>   connect.createServer(
>       connect.cookieParser()
>     , connect.session({ cookie: { domain : ".mydomain.com" }})
>   );
> ```

and

> ```
>  res.cookie('remember', 1, { domain : ".mydomain.com" });
> ```

should work.

Comment: How do I do that? I simply use Express to handle my cookies... I do req.session.abc='123';  console.log(req.session.abc);

Comment: Do I need the last part (res.cookie) if I already did it in createServer?

Comment: The arguments in createSession control the cookie(s) created to support the session.  If you create any cookies by hand, you have to set the domain by hand.  I believe.  Try it and see.

Comment: For **localhost** you **have to have two dots**, ``domain: 'localhost'`` does not work. This does work: ``domain: '.app.localhost'`` for all the subdomains of app.localhost, such as: ``api.app.localhost:3000/'``

Comment: see my answer here for more info on how to handle it on **localhost**: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22070413/2728686