# Using expressjs/nodejs store session logged in to redis

Tags: node.js, session, cookies, express, redis

I'm using express/nodejs to store sesssion logged-in to redis with the code:

```
app.use(express.session({
    key: 'myappname.sid',
    secret: "Some Secret!!!",
    store : new RedisStore({
        host : '127.0.0.1',,
        port : 6379,
    }),
    cookie : {
        maxAge : 604800 // one week
    }
}));
```

I check logged in status by:

```
function ensureAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) { return next(); }
      res.redirect('/login')
}
```

When i loggin successfully, i saw the session of both chrome cookie and redis.
But if i remove only one session on chrome cookie or redis, app will be no loggin status. 
Why does authenticating status depend on both chrome cookie and redis.

second question: I added domain like this

```
cookie : {
domain:"localhost", // or ".localhost"
maxAge : 604800 // one week
 }
```

but when loggin successfully, no session store on chrome cookie, why this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your second question, maxAge for cookie takes time in milliseconds. Your cookie would expire in 604 seconds.

For the first one, that is the correct way web security should work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
About second question, it does not depend on maxAge.

Answer (score 0):

Answer for question 1.
With localhost , we need two dot with subdomain like sub1.app.localhost
[How do I make my sessions last cross-subdomain in Node.js Express?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074509/how-do-i-make-my-sessions-last-cross-subdomain-in-node-js-express)