# Do cookies work on a localhost?

Tags: php, html, cookies

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cookies on localhost with explicit domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134290/cookies-on-localhost-with-explicit-domain)

this is my code after the user has logged in:

```
setcookie("user",$entered_username, time()+(60*60*5));
    setcookie("password",$entered_password, time()+(60*60*5));
    header('Location: frontpage.html');
```

This is my code on frontpage.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<?php
if (isset($_COOKIE["user"]))
  echo $_COOKIE["user"] ;
else
  echo "Welcome guest";
?>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

This does not work on my wamp local host? what is the problem?

Comment: 5 seconds of googling got me:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134290/cookies-on-localhost-with-explicit-domain

Comment: PHP code isn't evaluated inside .html files (by default). Are you sure it's actually running rather than just outputting the PHP code directly on the page?

Comment: Please don't store the password in a cookie

Answer (score 2):

`httpd.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName wibble.com
  DocumentRoot "some directory"
<VirtualHost>

<Directory "the same directory">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

And

```
LoadModule php5_module "C:/Program Files/PHP/php5apache2_2.dll"
```

hosts (`C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc`)

add an appropriate line

eg.

```
127.0.0.1   myhost.wibble.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes they work on localhost. Make up a domain and bung it into /etc/hosts. On  my PC I have C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc with a host of hosts for development.

Comment: Why isnt it working then? Is there a problem with my code?

Comment: Make sure you configuration is right, and change the extension.