# Unable to read cookie in php on localhost

Tags: php

PHP not reading cookie although I can see in browser.

```
//i set cookie in localhost/site/classes/php/user
setcookie("liu", $result[0]['user_id'], time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 30, "/");
//trying to access it in localhost/site/index.php
$loggedInUser = $_COOKIE['liu'];
```

Comment: The cookie is set by `setcookie`, but it won't be available in `$_COOKIE` until the page has reloaded.

Comment: I am reloading page. I check even after several minutes.

Comment: Why this question is down voted? @EjazKarim May be some of the add on is not allowing to set a cookie, your browser must be rejecting, did you tried on some other PC?

Comment: Array ( [PHPSESSID] => vfloicc82ec8hj8n0o0cc4f4m7) @nlsbshtr

Comment: @Mr.Alien I do... Still getting same error

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're running on localhost, you should explicitly set the cookie domain to `false`.

You could try:

```
setcookie("liu", $result[0]['user_id'], time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 30, "/", false);
```

Have a further look here: [Cookies on localhost with explicit domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134290/cookies-on-localhost-with-explicit-domain?lq=1)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot read a cookie you have set in the code above.

Cookies are sent with the headers to the browser.

PHP will be able to read the cookie only after the user navigates to the next page or you redirect him to a new page.

PHP will be able to read the cookie then because the browser will send it back via headers.

Read this: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

**Common Pitfalls:**

*Cookies will not become visible until the next loading of a page that the cookie should be visible for. To test if a cookie was successfully set, check for the cookie on a next loading page before the cookie expires.*

*Expire time is set via the expire parameter. A nice way to debug the existence of cookies is by simply calling* **print_r($_COOKIE);**

Answer (score 0):

We verify that we are not working in local, if we are in local we put the value of false in the variable $domain. If not, we pass the domain where the web is hosted.

```
$domain = ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] != 'localhost') ? $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] : false;
setcookie( 'liu', $result[0]['user_id'], time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 30, '/', $domain );
```

Comment: Please explain your answer.