# Secure cookie not working in php

Tags: php, cookies

I am trying to set the secure cookie into localhost and it doesn't work for me. My code is below :

```
<?php    
setcookie("TestCookie", "value1hostonly", time(), "/", "localhost.com", 0, true);
setcookie("TestCookie2", "value2subdom", time(), "/", "localhost", 0, true);

echo @$_COOKIE["TestCookie"];  
echo @$_COOKIE["TestCookie2"];  
?>
```

Output always show blank . Please guide me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Secure cookie not work on localhost . need  to test it on server and Change time() to time() + 500 or however many seconds until cookie expires .

Answer (score 0):

Your expiration time is set to now.

Change `time()` to `time() + 500` or however many seconds until cookie expires.

Comment: domain localhost is also a problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134290/cookies-on-localhost-with-explicit-domain