# chrome extension set cookie for localhost domain using chrome.cookies.set API

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cookies, google-chrome-extension, chromium

I have written a chrome extension which adds some cookie to domain in which my web app is running.

The API chrome.cookie.set() works for all domains except when I use the domain as "localhost". If I try to access the web app running locally using the domain "127.0.0.1" or "0.0.0.0" the API "chrome.cookies.set()" works as expected.

This does not work only when I use the domain as "localhost". How Can I fix this issue for "localhost" domain?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1134290/34397

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try cookie Domain = null or set the cookie to " " for localhost.