# Set cookie while returning a HTTP 204 - No Content

Tags: http, cookies, header, get, http-headers

Is it possible for us to set a cookie in a response with an HTTP 204 (No content) status?
I managed to set the Set-Cookie header while returning the 204 response (screenshot)

[image]

However, my browser does not seem to react to this.
My `document.cookie` does not yield what `Set-Cookie` wanted to do.

Answer (score 3):

Had this same question. Found this link: [204 No Content and cookies - Erik's Code](http://blog.dubbelboer.com/2014/06/01/204-cookie.html)

> What I found is that all major browsers, IE (6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11), FF (6 - 29), Safari (5 - 7), Opera (12 - 22) on both windows and Mac, set cookies on 204 http responses.

They provide the test code and a demo page.

Answer (score 1):

It won't be a problem of response status but the localhost domain. You'd better to use other domains to test cookies.

[Cookies on localhost with explicit domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134290/cookies-on-localhost-with-explicit-domain)

Answer (score 0):

The main problem here is not the 204 response code, but the fact that your `Set-Cookie` directive marks the cookie as `HttpOnly`. This means that JavaScript **cannot** access this cookie; that is in fact the *point* of `HttpOnly`.

So your example should work, but you should not and cannot verify it with `document.cookie`. Alternatives include the web development tools / plugins in browsers ("FireBug" or similar), or testing if the cookie is returned on the server itself.