# Cookies function working fine in all major browsers except Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cookies

The Java Script cookie work fine in all major browser but does not work in Chrome.

```
function createCookie(name, value, days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        var expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
    } else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/; domain=.198.XXX.XX.99";
}
```

Cookies are not set in Chrome.

Comment: Have you checked the cookie acceptance setting of your Chrome version? If so, and you want a cookie setting script that is widely used and is guaranteed to work in Chrome, let me know. It is a bit different from yours, though.

Comment: Drop the dot before IP.

Comment: @FrankConijn I checked . the phpsession cookie present in the  box but no cookies present for the above function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to access the page using the IP-address provided under *domain* and drop the *dot* before IP, or drop *domain* all together:

```
document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + ";path=/;domain=198.XXX.XX.99";
                                                                 |
                                   No dot (.) -------------------+
```

<sup>Here I assume *XXX.XX* is only obfuscation before posting here on Stack Overflow.</sup>

Note: As you can not wildcard IP-address in the *domain* portion of the Cookie, it becomes rather useless.

Chrome does not accept prepending *dot* to numeric IP address. E.g. FireFox accept either or. For domains it used to be mandatory, but is now optional.

- [RFC 2109](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2109#section-4.3.2)
- [RFC 2965](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2965#page-6)
- [RFC 6265](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265)

---

Edit: It is surely worth testing. I always use a BIND etc.+fake domain on local net/or standalones, thus never IP/localhost or the like. (At least last 10+ years.)

But there seems to be varying trouble around using IP/localhost:

- http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=56211
- [Cookies on localhost with explicit domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134290/cookies-on-localhost-with-explicit-domain)
- etc.

Though some of it is dated, do a thorough check or set up a fake domain.