# Cannot set cookie in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, cookies

I'm receiving from server such cookie:

```
SID=vDAqgF4KMKFvZmc1t6NevC7WgLe1cKssufK2OdwwSKKdK9ptkBDS2TNKeMYp472e; expires=Sun, 31 Jan 2100 22:00:00 GMT; Path=/; Domain=localhost; HttpOnly
```

I cannot set it into `document.cookie`.

I've tried different ways to fix it, like replacing `localhost` on `127.0.0.1` or removing `HttpOnly` flag, but it didn't help.

Comment: take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134290/cookies-on-localhost-with-explicit-domain
- in this answer a User says that in `localhost `you must use `""` or `null` like `Domain`... - so in your server side app/script try to omit the `domain` information.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't help. `Domain=false`, `Domain=null`, `Domain=''` or `Domain=` - none of this variants worked for me.

Comment: have you try to omit `domain`?
`SID=vDAqgF4KMKFvZmc1t6NevC7WgLe1cKssufK2OdwwSKKdK9ptkBDS2TNKeMYp472e; expires=Sun, 31 Jan 2100 22:00:00 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly`

Comment: Yes, I've tried it and got the same result. :(

Comment: The cookie is set by a server?  The server has the same origini that the page where you check the cookie. (all localhost?)