# PHP - cookie is never set

Tags: php, cookies

I'm trying to set a `cookie` with this lines

```
if(!isset($_COOKIE["testAgain"]))
        setcookie("testAgain", mt_rand());
```

The problem is that, even if I can see in the `response headers` the following lines:

```
Set-Cookie: testAgain=15146202
```

When I change the page, the `cookie` is not in `$_COOKIE` and it tries to set it again.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Have you checked if your browser has cookies enabled? Are you trying in incognito browser?

Comment: Yes, the browser have cookie enabled, as long as I am able to set them Client side. 
No, did not tried incognito browser

Comment: Have you tried specifying a domain and path for the cookie?

Comment: It looks like a Browser problem. Are you running on Localhost? It could be this bug. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134290/cookies-on-localhost-with-explicit-domain

Comment: @nv1t it seems to be that. Going to check it right now

Comment: seems to be a chrome bug for localhost, in firefox I see it