# Cookie is not set on localhost in chrome or firefox

Tags: java, google-chrome, cookies, jersey

I am working with a Jersey server which returns a cookie in the following way:

```
return Response.ok()
    .cookie(
        new NewCookie(
            "userAccessToken", userTokenDTO.getToken(), "/", "", 
            "what is this", 3600, false
        )
    ).build();
```

When I call the method which returns the cookie, I get the following result in chrome:
[image: Request and response headers]

I can even see that chrome has recognized my cookie:
[image: Cookie recognized]

But for some reason it isn't set in the cookie tab:

[image: No cookie shown]

I have tried setting the domain both to false, null, "", creating an entry in the hosts file renaming 127.0.0.1.

```
return Response.ok()
    .cookie(
            new NewCookie(
                    "userAccessToken", userTokenDTO.getToken(), "/", "127.0.0.1",
                    "what is this", 3600, false)
    ).build();
```

Works in IE 11, but still not Chrome nor Firefox...

I have tried multiple time to insert another host name for 127.0.0.1. In this example it is text.myexample.com. It still doesn't work in any other browser than IE11.

```
return Response.ok()
    .cookie(
            new NewCookie(
                    "userAccessToken", userTokenDTO.getToken(), "/", "test.myexample.com",
                    "what", 7200, false)
    ).build();
```

I tried to do the following in the console of Google Chrome:

```
document.cookie = "userAccessToken=72bebbe0-44fd-45ce-a6e1-accb72201eff;Version=1;Comment=what;Domain=test.myexample.com;Path=/;Max-Age=7200"
```

Which is the cookie in the header returned by the server in Chrome. That works fine. I have literally no clue what is going on here.

Comment: Maybe this is related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134290/cookies-on-localhost-with-explicit-domain try in your hosts file put a hostname for your application, e.g. `127.0.0.1 myapp.local` and use it as a hostname.

Comment: I have already tried that with multiple different names with no luck.

Comment: Its a issue with localhost only  ,works well on other urls  see below link here cookie works but in local it fails http://jerseyexample-ravikant.rhcloud.com/rest/jws/say/Hi

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Turns out the problem was related to the fetch library I am using. If you do not include `{ credentials: "same-origin" }` in the request, the response cookie isn't being set.

For more information, see: https://github.com/github/fetch/issues/386.

Comment: I used `{ credentials: "include" }` recently, and it fixed this issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Its a issue with localhost only  ,works well on other urls  see below link here cookie works but in local it fails
 http://jerseyexample-ravikant.rhcloud.com/rest/jws/say/Hi

for localhost you can go with below .

```
return Response.status(200).entity(output)

                .header("Set-Cookie", "userAccessToken=toke;lang=en-US; Path=/; Domain=localhost")
                .build();
```

[image]

See the network tab

Response Headers
Content-Length:18 
Content-Type:text/html 
Date:Fri, 25 Nov 2016 10:19:15 GMT 
ProcessingTime:0 millisecs 
Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1 
Set-Cookie:userAccessToken=toke;lang=en-US; Path=/; Domain=localhost

[image: Network tab]

Comment: Can i see the network request tab for the request setting the cookie? Your example isn't working on my own project.

Comment: added the image in original answer