# Cookie not set after redirect from remote domain

Tags: cookies, phoenix-framework, setcookie

I have a phoenix server running on heroku, and web application that runs on `localhost/127.0.0.1`.

What I am trying to do, is login with GitHub OAuth, set jwt token and redirect back to `localhost/127.0.0.1` with cookie with token.

This is the response headers after redirection:

[image]

As you can see, the cookie is sent correctly, however is not set by the browser.

This is the code responsible for setting cookie and redirection:

`"web" -> conn
           |> put_status(302)
           |> put_resp_cookie("bearer", jwt, [http_only: false, path: "/"])
           |> redirect external: "localhost:8100"`

I've been trying solutions proposed here: [Cookies on localhost with explicit domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134290/cookies-on-localhost-with-explicit-domain) but none of them seems to work.

When I run server locally, everything works fine, however when I change 
`|> redirect external: "localhost:8100"` to `|> redirect external: "127.0.0.1:8100"` the same issue occurs.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: You cannot set cookies on another domain like this. You can send the data back as a URL argument if you want though. Will that be good enough? `|> redirect(external: "http://...:8100?jwt=#{jwt}")`.

Comment: What about security? Is it save to include jwt token in the url?