# Prebid Example Does Not Work When Running on Local Dev Server

Tags: javascript, ads, double-click-advertising, prebid.js

**TL;DR: Is it possible to test Prebid header bidding with Prebid.js v1.6.0 with a locally running web server?**

I have created a library for integrating [Prebid](http://prebid.org) header bidding into web applications built with [React](https://reactjs.org). It works fine using Prebid 0.34.6 and I use it successfully in production.

I'm now migrating my library to use the latest version of Prebid, 1.6.0. I've followed the [migration guide carefully](http://prebid.org/dev-docs/prebid-1.0-API.html) and implemented all the changes outlined there.

To test my code, I've set up a demo application that runs on a local dev server.

In the debug output of the application, I can see that bids are received (log says `INFO: Bids Received for Auction with id: aa5d34f4-3eb7-4cb0-a756-6f7cc4a18568`).

However, no creatives are shown in the ad slots. My *bidsBackHandler* callback function receives an empty object as argument. When I call `pbjs.getAdserverTargeting()` on the browser's developer console, I also get an empty object.

On the [Prebid example pages](http://prebid.org/dev-docs/examples/basic-example.html), there is a basic Prebid.js example shown for integrating Prebid into a web page, along with a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bhn3xk2j/1078/).

I use the exact same and units and GPT configuration as used in the fiddle in my demo application, to no avail – no creative in the ad slots, only the “house ad” fallback, empty response to the bids back handler, empty ad server targeting.

Then I discovered if I copy the code from the basic Prebid.js example fiddle to an HTML page on my local dev server, it also fails the same way – no creative in the ad slots, only the “house ad” fallback, empty response to the bids back handler, empty ad server targeting.

I then created a sandbox with my demo (→ https://codesandbox.io/s/k5w8mr9o23), and there, I do get the desired result, the demo creative is shown.

It seems that with Prebid 1.x, you cannot get ad slots filled when running on localhost.

**Can anyone confirm this? Is there a way to make this work?**

Comment: Your sandbox seems to have an error? Can you instead provide a git repo I can try locally

Comment: Oh, sorry, I must have accidentally broken the sandbox when I was trying out stuff. It works now, please try again. You can download the code using the download button on the sandbox

Comment: What should I expect to see? It works for me locally as well on mac?

Comment: When I run it locally, in both slots, a house ad is displayed. Expected is to have a prebid ad in the upper slot and house ad only in the lower one. Do you have a prebid ad in the upper slot when running it Locally?

Comment: This is what I see in Sandbox https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Brqc.png and same in local

Comment: Do you have an ad blocker installed? It obviously does not work with an ad blocker

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169535/discussion-between-tarun-lalwani-and-patrick-hund).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### What's happening

The Prebid library needs cookies to work. It fails on your local dev server because [cookies are problematic when running the web server on localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1134290/300805).
You can verify this by typing `document.cookie` in your JavaScript console on the codesandbox demo and on your local server: a `__gads` cookie will be set where the demo works, but not on localhost.

`__gads` is [a cookie set on your domain by Google ads](https://policies.google.com/technologies/types). This is probably an issue on their side, not Prebid's.

#### How to fix it

The easiest way to fix this, is to avoid pointing your browser to `localhost` (or to `127.0.0.1` or other local IP addresses).
Instead set a different hostname for 127.0.0.1 (preferably containing at least two dots), and use such one.
You can do this by adding an entry to your hosts file. [Here instructions for Windows, Mac, Linux](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/27350/beginner-geek-how-to-edit-your-hosts-file/)).

In my case (Linux system; should also work on Mac) I added the following line to `/etc/hosts`:

`127.0.0.1   www.localhost.localdomain`

Then directed my browser to [www.localhost.localdomain:3000](http://www.localhost.localdomain:3000/) and everything was working.
I can see that the `__gads` cookie is set at this address, while it's not set on [localhost:3000](http://localhost:3000/).

Comment: Great answer, we should probably add this info to the github page