# How do I set cookie from localhost

Tags: javascript, authentication, cookies, xmlhttprequest, localhost

I've read through the suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134290/cookies-on-localhost-with-explicit-domain). I'm making an XHR request to my service in order to get the cookie. I've tried ensuring that the Domain is missing from the cookie (not just an empty string) -

```
Set-Cookie: file-auth=MTU0ODIzODU1M3xEdi1CQkFFQ180SUFBUXdCREFBQUh2LUNBQUVGZG1Gc2RXVVRaRzkzYm14dllXUXRZWFYwYUc5eWFYcGxaQT09fPzBg_EP9S6wn_7gAz0iUtS1cOOaeo78VAMdD5xxhunF; Path=/; Expires=Thu, 24 Jan 2019 10:15:53 GMT
```

I've tried adjusting my host file so that I make the request to `app.localhost.com:12350` and then specifying the domain in the `Set-Cookie` header -

```
Set-Cookie: file-auth=MTU0ODIzODg4NnxEdi1CQkFFQ180SUFBUXdCREFBQUh2LUNBQUVGZG1Gc2RXVVRaRzkzYm14dllXUXRZWFYwYUc5eWFYcGxaQT09fCdT3LhVhHIA6mPq_65ndnP1XFD2IEzLpxCmiaosHZA5; Path=/; Domain=app.localhost.com; Expires=Thu, 24 Jan 2019 10:21:26 GMT
```

My initial XHR (GET) request is to `http://app.localhost.com:12350/test/file_service/setcookie`

with the following headers

```
GET /test/file_service/setcookie HTTP/1.1
Host: app.localhost.com:12350
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: application/json
Origin: http://app.localhost.com
Authorization: <MY-JWT>
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36
Referer: http://app.localhost.com/tutorials
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
```

And the response comes back -

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://app.localhost.com
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Content-Length
Content-Encoding: gzip
Set-Cookie: file-auth=MTU0ODIzODg4NnxEdi1CQkFFQ180SUFBUXdCREFBQUh2LUNBQUVGZG1Gc2RXVVRaRzkzYm14dllXUXRZWFYwYUc5eWFYcGxaQT09fCdT3LhVhHIA6mPq_65ndnP1XFD2IEzLpxCmiaosHZA5; Path=/; Domain=app.localhost.com; Expires=Thu, 24 Jan 2019 10:21:26 GMT
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Vary: Origin
Date: Wed, 23 Jan 2019 10:21:26 GMT
Content-Length: 23
Content-Type: application/x-gzip
```

But then when make a new GET request to `http://app.localhost.com:12350/test/file_service/file?` (not XHR - I'm just clicking a link in the browser), the cookie isn't sent. Looking in the cookies tab on the chrome debugger, there's nothing set for the domain

[image: chrome-debugger]

How do I make this work?

Answer (score 0):

XMLHttpRequest has an attribute `withCredentials` which defaults to `false`. This attribute defines whether a `Set-Cookie` header will be honored for cross origin requests.

If you're hosting the page at `http://app.localhost.com` but calling `http://app.localhost.com:12350` to get the cookie, the `Set-Cookie` header will be ignored if the `withCredentials` attribute is not set to true.

Setting `withCredentials` will depend on how you're making the request. In older browsers -

```
var client = new XMLHttpRequest()
client.open("GET", "./")
client.withCredentials = true
```

But a more modern solution is -

`fetch("./", { credentials:"include" }).then(/* … */)`

See [here](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#cors-protocol-and-credentials)