# Cookies don't get stored in localhost

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, cross-domain

I'm trying to set a cookie when a user logs into the application but i can't seem to get the cookie to get stored on chrome or firefox but it does work on postman.

Here is the part of the code when i try to set my cookie.

```
  res.cookie("jwt", token, {
    domain: ".localhost",
    path: "/",
    expires: new Date(
      Date.now() + process.env.JWT_COOKIE_EXPIRES_IN * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
    ),
    httpOnly: true
  });
```

POSTMAN output :

[image]

And my CORS setup :

[image]

Note : my server is on port 3900 and my client is on 3000

Comment: Did you try removing the . before localhost?

Comment: yes it doesn't work

Comment: Sorry no idea. :/

Comment: try omitting the domain part when setting cookies on localhost, check this answer for more infos: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134290/cookies-on-localhost-with-explicit-domain

Comment: just to double check, considering that this is a HTTP only cookie, how did you check that you don't have it in the browser?

Comment: it is an HTTP only cookie , as for the browser i opened developers tools > application > cookies > my domain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use localhost:3000 as domain because it is your actual domain for client side. localhost by default take port 80 as http request.

```
res.cookie("jwt", token, {
    domain: ".localhost:3000",
    path: "/",
    expires: new Date(
      Date.now() + process.env.JWT_COOKIE_EXPIRES_IN * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
    ),
    httpOnly: true
  });
```

Comment: for me, `.localhost:3000` didn't work but `.localhost` did. for context, this was a next.js site where i was setting a pure client-only cookie using `next-client-cookies` npm package.