# Cookies dont get stored because of path with req.cookie

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, cookies

Hello I got a similar problem as this one : [Cookies don't get stored in localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57349184/cookies-dont-get-stored-in-localhost) but the difference is that for me it works when I put path:'/' (the default path) and path:'/login' (which is the current client side page when the cookie is trying to be stored at the end of the login process) but it doesn't for any other path.

```
res.cookie(`api`,token,{
    domain:'localhost',
    path:'/account',
    expires: new Date(Date.now()+7*24*60*60*1000),
    httpOnly: true
});
```

My server is on port 3000

Edit: I need to add that I have a middleware like this in my app.js file

```
app.use("/auth/", authRoutes);
```

authRoutes is the module file where I put the different routes like /login and /register. So when I submit the login form it is calling the /auth/login route server side which will execute the login function where I try to create the cookie after all the email/password verifications. I just tried path as '/auth' in the res.cookie function and it actually worked. Could that be the problem ? That I am trying to create a cookie in a function that is considering '/' as /auth/ because it is a middleware. I don't know if it's clear but I was thinking maybe it is somehow related even if I wouldn't understand why.

Edit 2 : In my app, Express serves static files of my react front end app. What I want to do is put a httponly cookie on the user's browser after login that will be sent back to server only when user visit the '/account' page to verify the user's identity and if he is still connected.

Comment: The correct answer on the above SO link you shared expects a port number. Did you try that?

Comment: Yes I did, it didn't work with the port number, same with the "." or both in the same time. 'localhost' like this works well but only with '/' and '/login' as path

Comment: I just edited original post with some details because I found that '/auth' path is working too