# Couldn't set cookie using ngx-cookie-service

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ngx-cookie-service

I'm using `angular 9` and I need to set a cookie. I'm using `ngx-cookie-service 3.0.4` and I'm trying to do that like the following:

```
this.cookieService.set("cookieName", user.tokenId, date, "/", "localhost:4200");
```

and when I'm trying to get out this one I get null in the response and in the browser I'm not seeing this cookie. I'm trying to get out the result like the following:

```
console.log("COOKIE: ", this.cookieService.get("cookieName));
```

What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When setting cookies for the localhost, you can not use `'localhost:4200'` as the domain. This is by design and you can read more about it here: [Cookies on localhost with explicit domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134290/cookies-on-localhost-with-explicit-domain)

In this case, you can pass in `null` or omit the domain entirely when the application is running on the localhost.

```
const hostName = isLocal ? null : 'HOST_NAME';
this.cookieService.set("cookieName", user.tokenId, date, "/", hostName);
```