# Add cookies in playwright test

Tags: javascript, puppeteer, e2e-testing, playwright

No matter what I do I get an error (either X.cookies is not a function or X.addCookies is not a function). I tried with context, page.context. browserContext etc. and it always ends up in the same way (ok, page.context as well as browserContext are undefined so error is different).

Context:

- Playwright Version: 1.4.2
- Operating System: Ubuntu 20.4
- Node.js version: 10.15.1
- Browser: Chromium

Code:

```
beforeEach(async function fn() {
this.timeout(20000);
browser = await chromium.launch({ headless: false });

const context = await browser.newContext();
page = await context.newPage();

await page
  .goto("http://localhost:4200/#/login", {
    waitUntil: "networkidle0",
  })
  .catch(() => {});
```

});

and in test:

```
      // await context.addCookies([
  //   { name: "csrftoken", value: cookieToken, path: "/" },
  //   { name: "sessionid", value: cookieSession, path: "/" },
  // ]);
  // await context.cookies();
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

right after you have your context, you should be able to use it as an example below:
`await context.addCookies([{name:"csrftoken", value: "mytokenvalue123", url: "your.application.url"}]);`

Answer (score 5):

I had to use context directly instead of browser context, otherwise some data would not load correctly (specifically in a SvelteKit app):

```js
test('index page has expected content when logged in', async ({ page, context }) => {
    await context.addCookies([
        { name: 'sessionid', value: 'random', path: '/', domain: 'localhost' }
    ]);

    await page.goto('/');
    expect(await page.textContent('h1')).toBe('My title');
    console.log(await context.cookies());
});
```

Comment: Alternatively, I started with `browser`, created a new context, and then created a `newPage` off that context to get it working. I like this solution better although I haven't tried it.

Answer (score 4):

Setting cookies is pretty straightforward. You can to take advantage of the browser fixture.

```
test("Go Test An Application", async ({ page, browser }) => {

    // Using the browser fixture, you can get access to the BrowserContext
    const browserContext = await browser.newContext();

    // Add cookies to the browserContext
    const cookieVals = await setCookieVals();
    browserContext.addCookies(cookieVals)

    // First we will go to the Applicaiton URL
    const appURL = "https://stackoverflow.com/"
    page.goto(`${appURL}`);

    await page.waitForTimeout(3000);

});

export async function setCookieVals() {

    const cookies = [
        {name:"cookie1", value:"349", path:"/", domain:"stackoverflow"},
        {name:"cookie2", value:"1", path:"/", domain:"stackoverflow"},
        {name:"cookie3", value:"4000", path:"/", domain:"stackoverflow"},
    ]

    return cookies;
}
```

Comment: How do I set `localhost` as domain ? For cookies in general the domain [should be omitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134290/cookies-on-localhost-with-explicit-domain), for playwright it is required. Or is playwright not supposed to be used on a local machine (i.e. before the deployment) ?

Answer (score 2):

In order to set cookies with `playwright`, you would need to add both `path` & `domain` or `url`. Cf. the commented code in [addCookies docs](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-browsercontext#browser-context-add-cookies)

```js
**browserContext.addCookies(cookies)**

cookies <Array<Object>>
name <string>
value <string>
url <string> either url or domain / path are required. Optional. // ***** NOTE *****
domain <string> either url or domain / path are required Optional. // ***** NOTE *****
path <string> either url or domain / path are required Optional. // ***** NOTE *****
expires <number> Unix time in seconds. Optional.
httpOnly <boolean> Optional.
secure <boolean> Optional.
sameSite <"Strict"|"Lax"|"None"> Optional.

returns: <Promise<void>>
```

This is different behavior than [standard behavior](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie) where domain is optional.

Answer (score 1):

we can use the current working page context to add the cookies.

```
 const browserContext = page.context();

    // Add cookies to the browserContext
    browserContext.addCookies([
      {
        name: 'next-auth.session-token',
        value: 'FAKE_TOKEN',
        domain: 'localhost',
        path: '/',
        expires: -1,
        httpOnly: true,
        secure: false,
        sameSite: 'Lax',
      },
    ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had some struggle, so I ended to use this:

```
  await page.addInitScript((cookie: string) => {
    document.cookie = cookie;
  }, cookie);
```

Reference: https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-page#page-add-init-script

Answer (score -2):

const context is set only inside the beforeEach method and it's not avilable in your test.

Define it as a global variable

Comment: Please share an example!