# django built-in authentication system not working with react

Tags: reactjs, django, authentication, django-rest-framework

I am building a django-react app, using Django to render the templates, Django REST framework for the api endpoints, and React on top of django templates.
I am using `'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication'` and I have implemented the authentication routes but django's built-in authentication methods (`login`, `logout`, `authenticate`) only seem to work with the templates rendered by django and not with the React components. By this I mean if i have a view like

```
def home_page(request, *args, **kwargs):
    print("local USER >>>", request.user)
    print("local SESSION >>>", request.session)
    return render(request, 'pages/homepage.html',
        {}, status=200)
```

and I visit the route after logging in, it would print out both the `user` and the `session` object.
But for the api views,

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly])
def post_list_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    print("api USER >>>", request.user)
    print("api SESSION >>>", request.session)
    ...
```

I get `AnnonymousUser` and `None` even if I'm logged in.

When i checked the browser cookies, i found both the `csrftoken` and `sessionid` cookies.
But if I try a post request, I get `403 Forbidden` error with "Authentication credentials were not provided." message. (I have also set `withCredentials` to true.) And in the request headers there was only the `X-CSRFToken` header (with the token) but `sessionid` cookie was missing.

At this point, I just don't know what to do next. Should I manually set the session cookie? Or, should I customize the built-in methods? (If so, please tell me how I could do that.)
**What am I doing wrong here and how can I fix it?**

edit:

xhr headers for GET request:
[image: xhr headers for GET request]

xhr headers for POST request:
[image: xhr headers for POST request]

axios configurations:

```js
const options = {
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken
    },
    withCredentials: true 
};

axios.post(url, data, options)
.then(response => {
    console.log(response);
    commentInput.current.value = '';
})
.catch(error => console.log(error));
```

Comment: You should send session cookie with every request made to your Django server

Answer (score 1):

turns out i was making a request to `localhost` and for [some reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134290/cookies-on-localhost-with-explicit-domain) you cannot set cookies to it. the issue was solved by simply changing the `url` to `127.0.0.1`.

Answer (score 0):

Setting `withCredentials` should to the job:

```
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true
```

Do you set it this way?

If it doesn't help, could you please post server response header, the client request header and the axios config and example how you send request (on client).

One question, why did you go with Django templates + React? Why you didn't separate React from Django?

Comment: No i did not set the configurations in that particular way but i did pass it as an argument. The reason i used django templates + react is because i had to use django-mptt and it's template tags to construct comment trees and i havent found a way to implement it with react... at least not yet.