# Laravel Sanctum - Store cookies on localhost subdomain

Tags: laravel, vue.js, cookies, laravel-sanctum

I'm working on an webapp (Laravel/Vue) with a subdomain per organisation (companyone.mydomain.com, companytwo.mydomain.com, ...)

As authentication system I'm using Laravel Sanctum with cookies. While setting a cookie is working on localhost it's not working when using subdomains locally.

My backend is running on `localhost:8000` while the frontend is running on `localhost:8080`. For cors reasons I've added a proxy property in `vue.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
    devServer: {
        disableHostCheck: true,
        proxy: 'http://localhost:8000',
    },
};
```

I've changed the `/etc/hosts` file so I can simulate subdomains locally

```
127.0.0.1  localhost
127.0.0.1  mydomain.com
127.0.0.1  companyone.mydomain.com
127.0.0.1  companytwo.mydomain.com
```

On the backend I've added the following lines to the `.env` file (and restarted the `php artisan serve` script)

```
SESSION_DOMAIN=.mydomain.com
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=mydomain.com
```

In the Authcontroller I'm returning the cookie like this

```
$token = $user->createToken(Str::random(10))->plainTextToken;
$cookie = cookie('mydomain_api', $token, 60 * 24);
        
return response([
   'token' => $token,
   'user' => new AuthResource($user)
], 200)->withCookie($cookie);
```

The cookie settings are the following

```
$domain = null
$secure = true
$httpOnly = true
$sameSite = 'None'
```

When calling the login function I'm receiving the cookie in my browser like this

[image: Response cookies]

but Application -> Cookies stays empty

[image: Cookies are empty]

The request header

[image: Request header]

When sending another request to the api, no cookies are added.
How can I get the cookie in the Cookies storage?

[EDIT 1] When hardcoding the domain on the backend to `mydomain.com` I'm getting the following error in the browser

[image: Error message]

Comment: Huh. Why is the domain in the first image "localhost"?

Comment: @user202729 I don't know but when hardcoding the domain to ```mydomain.com``` I'm getting an error. See [EDIT 1]

Comment: It seems that you should just access the website with `companyone.mydomain.com` in the browser? Are you doing that already...

Comment: @user202729 That's what I'm doing. All the requests are being sent from ```companyone.mydomain.com``` actually from ```companyone.mydomain.com:8080```

Comment: Weird? Could be because there's only one dot. https://stackoverflow.com/a/1188145/5267751

Comment: @user202729 companyone.mydomain.com has two dots

Answer (score 0):

Update your `.env`

```
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=localhost:8080,mydomain.com:8080,companyone.mydomain.com:8080,companytwo.mydomain.com:8080,::1,localhost:8080,localhost:3000
```

Answer (score 0):

try to add folowing lines in your in .htaccess file

```
# Handle Authorization Header
# RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
# RewriteRule .* - [E=Authorization:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```