# document.cookie returning empty string

Tags: javascript, cookies, django-rest-framework, frontend

I am trying to get a cookie in my client side javascript by calling 'document.cookie' but it returns ''. I know a cookie exists because I passed 'Set-Cookie' in my response from django's rest framework and the browser's dev tools show that a cookie exists.

[image: dev tools shows cookie 'userID']

but again, when running 'document.cookie' in dev tools console window, nothing is returned:

[image]

The cookie doesn't have 'HttpOnly' flag set. I'm not sure how else to get existing cookies using javascript.

Comment: Hey, the html page is being rendered by the server or is it a local html file?

Comment: @LakshayaU. the image says `127.0.0.1:8000`

Comment: @Bravo Oh yeah it does 

Comment: LOL. thanks guys. i just came across the buried SO post about this problem. Apparently, the cookie's 'domain' must explicitly be OMITTED when working in a localhost environment. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134290/cookies-on-localhost-with-explicit-domain/1188145#1188145 what's strange is, the answer states not even an empty string should be set on it but i did that in my backend and it worked.