Session Cookie Not Persisting in Browser on Fetch/Axios Request with Express, Passport, and NextJs
I've been working on an authentication flow using Express, Passport, and Redis for session management on the backend, with a React (Next.js) frontend. The sessions are correctly created and stored in the Redis store upon login, but the session cookie doesn't seem to persist in the browser for subsequent requests, even though it's visible in Redis.
Backend Setup (Express + Passport + Redis):
I've configured CORS to accept requests from my frontend, initialized sessions with express-session and connect-redis, and am using Passport for authentication. The logout route explicitly destroys the session and clears the cookie, yet re-login doesn't seem to set the session correctly in the browser.
index.js:
    redisClient.connect().catch(console.error);

let redisStore = new RedisStore({
    client: redisClient,
});

// redisClient.flushDb().then(() => console.log('Current database cleared'));

// instantianting cors and cookie-session
app.use(
    cors({
        origin: ['http://localhost:3000', '*'],
        credentials: true,
        methods: "GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE",
        
    })
);
app.use(express.json());

Logout.js:
router.get("/logout", (req, res) => {
    req.logout(function (err) {
        if (err) { return next(err); }
        req.session.destroy(() => {
            res.clearCookie('auth-session');
            console.log("User logged out successfully");
            res.status(200).json({ message: "User logged out successfully" });
        });
    });
});

function to retrieve user in session :
router.get("/login/retrieve", isAuth, async (req, res) => {
    const { user } = req;
    res.status(200).json({
        message: "User is logged in, user object retrieved successfully",
        user
    });
});

the login function :
router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local', {
    failureFlash: true // Enable flash messages for authentication failures
}), (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.user);
    if (req.user.Error) {
        console.log(req.user.Error);
        res.status(401).json({ error: true, message: req.user.Error });
    } else if (req.user && !req.user.Error) {
        // Authentication successful
        res.status(200).json({
            error: false,
            message: "Successfully Logged In",
            user: req.user,
        });
    }
});

Front-end Login function :
export const LoginAction = async (values: z.infer<typeof LoginSchema>) => {
    // Validate the input fields first.
    const validatedFields = LoginSchema.safeParse(values);
    const auth = cookies().get('auth-session')!

    if (!validatedFields.success) {
        // Providing more detailed information about the validation errors.
        return {
            error: "Invalid fields",
            details: validatedFields.error.format(), // This will provide detailed info about what exactly is wrong.
        };
    }

    const { email, password } = validatedFields.data;
    try {
        const apiGateway = process.env.API_GATEWAY_URL;
         const response = await axios.post(`${apiGateway}/auth/login`, {
            email,
            password,
        }, {
            withCredentials: true,
            headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${process.env.AUTHORIZATION_HEADER}`,
                // "Cookie": `auth-session=${auth.value}`
            }
        });

        // Assuming the API sends back the user data on successful login
        // You can adjust this based on what your API actually returns
        if (response.data && response.status === 200) {
            return { success: 'Login Success', user: response.data };
        } else {
            // Handle non-successful responses, e.g., 404, 500 etc.
            return { error: "Login failed", details: `Received status code: ${response.status}` };
        }
    } catch (e) {
        console.error("An unexpected error happened:", e);
        // Differentiating between Axios errors and other types of errors
        
        return { error: "Your email or password is incorrect. Please try again."};
    }
};


Have you tried changing localhost to 127.0.0.1? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134290/cookies-on-localhost-with-explicit-domain/1188145#1188145
