# how to cache data on wcf rest service depending on ASP.NET Membership token

Tags: asp.net, wcf, caching, web

We are developing an ASP.NET web application, this application will generate pages base on meta data (automatic page and controls generation), after this generation a javascript framework will load data for every control found on the generated page by invoking the WCF Rest service

my first question is : is it possible to share session data between the ASP.NET web application and WCF Rest service and how to do that? for the first uses we will deploy the ASP.NET web application and its service on the same machin to reduce complexity

my second question is : wich cache-framework you recommend to cache data on the WCF Rest services? we will not cache the output responses of the wcf service instead we will cache the modified user data on the service to simulate a user session

I would appreciate any help on how to deal with this problem

Thanks in advance

Regards

Answer (score 1):

A good article on [asp.net sessions from wcf](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wenlong/archive/2010/02/21/using-asp-net-sessions-from-wcf.aspx)

I don't have any problems with System.Web.HttpRuntime.Cache in WCF (I am only hosting the WCF in IIS - for sure). MemCache is very popular otherwise.

Comment: Hi Neil and thank's for your answer, the problème with the asp.net session from wcf is that ower WCF service is a REST service, wich means I think that there is no cookies communicated to the service by its clients? and the second problem is that wcf service client is a JQuery client.

Comment: "AJAX calls only send Cookies if the url you're calling is on the same domain as your calling script." - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2870371/why-jquery-ajax-not-sending-session-cookie