# Sencha 2 sends doesnt use same session when sending requests

Tags: sencha-touch-2

See attachement, I log in an user to the server with Spring Security, and after log in I do a GET to get the adult object. But Sencha 2 doesnt use the same session, you can see in the server log that an other session is created. It doesnt seem like Sencha 2 persist a cookie (when I look in cookies in Chrome debugger)[image].

How come Sencha doesnt persist and use the cookie sent from the server?

[image]

Comment: i think, here is your answer
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11170488/getting-cookies-in-sencha-touch-2-0-using-ajax-request