# Cookies not saved in Sencha Touch 2

Tags: ajax, cookies, sencha-touch-2, setcookie

I have a web service "someWebServiceOnServer" that sends back a json response and a Cookie. If I hit this URL through the browser, I see the following:

`{"IsAuth":true,"Message":"","UserName":"guest"}`

And if I inspect the page Resources -> Cookies, I see a Cookie set.

Now in my Sencha Touch 2 application, I am making an ajax call as follows:

`Ext.Ajax.request({

                url: 'someWebServiceOnServer',

                useDefaultXhrHeader: false,

                callback: function(options, success, response) {

                console.log(response.responseText)

                },

});`

On running this, I get the JSON response as expected. But the cookie is not set. Also I cannot find the cookie in the response header. Why does this happen ?

Note:  CORS has been implemented on the server and my application can access this service. I have not used `withCredentials: true,` since this throws an error `XMLHttpRequest cannot load . Cannot use wildcard in Access-Control-Allow-Origin when credentials flag is true.` .

Cookies are already enabled on my browser.

I need the cookie since I will be making subsequent calls that will send this cookie info back to the server.

Comment: Is your problem fixed? If Yes can you share your solution?

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem, could you please suggest a solution? Many thanks!

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11616523/cookie-not-saved-in-sencha-touch-2-application?answertab=active#tab-top it is basically `withCredentials: true, useDefaultXhrHeader: false`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

Add the following headers to the server response.

`Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://clientdomain.com

Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true`

And add `withCredentials: true` in the Ajax request.

Answer (score 2):

For IIS WCF with ExtJS request apply this to web.config (eg. for localhost so locally hosted application for example via SenchaTouch packagedr or PhoneGap):

```
<system.webServer>
          <httpProtocol>
            <customHeaders>
              <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="http://localhost" />
              <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept" />
              <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />
            </customHeaders>
          </httpProtocol>
        </system.webServer>
```

And In Ext.JS request use those parameters:

```
disableCaching: true,
useDefaultXhrHeader: false,
withCredentials: true
```

This in turn forces Ext.ajax.request to use cookies.