# Access response cookie via cors xmlHttpRequest- Object

Tags: javascript, cookies, xmlhttprequest, http-post, cors

My client JavaScript- application is sending a simple POST CORS request to my server. Everything works fine so far and the server responses with "OK" and a cookie.

I can see the cookie in firebug.

I want to access the cookie in xhr.onload ..but I can't see the cookie or a cookie propertiy in the xhr object..

How can I access the cookie?

Thanks for all answers!!

Comment: Note the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14462423/cross-domain-post-request-is-not-sending-cookie-ajax-jquery/14472492#14472492 You can't read/write cross-domain requests from your JavaScript.

Comment: Okay then, I hoped there would be a way. Thanks anyways!