# Running an Ionic app as a PWA on Firebase hosting

Tags: google-app-engine, ionic-framework, cookies, cross-browser, cross-domain

### Background

We have a large Ionic v1 app that runs on Android (by obtaining it from the Google Play Store) and also on our development machines via "ionic serve".

The app uses a Google App Engine (GAE) website as a backend server.

The server maintains sessions for each user by means of a cookie. We don't store much data in the session, but we need to securely identify the user making each request. When the app runs successfully, the GAE server code creates a cookie that contains the session ID and sends it to the Ionic client code when responding to each HTTP request.

> Note:
>
> That the Ionic code does not access the cookie in any way. It is only
> necessary that the same cookie be sent back to the GAE server with each
> subsequent request so that the GAE code recognizes the user.

### The goal

We would like to serve the Ionic code by use of Firebase Hosting. We can in fact do so in both of two modes:

1. Keeping the Ionic code on our dev machine, running "firebase serve", and going to "localhost:5000" on the browser
2. Deploying the Ionic code to the Firebase host and going to "xxxx.firebaseapp.com" on the browser

***Everything works!*** Uh, except for one little thing, which we've been trying to solve for weeks...

### The problem

The cookie used by the GAE code to manage session continuity, and sent in responses to HTTP requests generated by the GAE code, does not come back in the next request from the Ionic app running on Firebase. So the GAE app always responds as though the user is not yet logged in.

In fact, further testing shows that the session cookie sent in responses to HTTP requests does not even get set in the browser (so of course it's not sent back to the GAE code with the next HTTP request). The GAE code on the backend server always responds as if this is the first HTTP request of a session.

### What we've solved already

- The problem is not the fact that Ionic does not support cookies. We know this is not the problem because the app runs fine as an Android app and also via "ionic serve". In both cases, the GAE backend is able to maintain sessions using a cookie to store the session ID from one request to the next.
- The problem does not get solved by using "memcache" instead of cookies for GAE session support, because even if you use memcache, you still need the cookie for the session ID. If you wish, you can go with the default and let GAE session support use cookies; in that case, it will use the same cookie for both the session ID and any other session data.
- The problem does not get solved by using "__session" as the name of the cookie. Firebase does in fact support using such a cookie name, but apparently only in the context of running Firebase Hosting with Cloud Functions. Cloud Functions are for running backend code, not client code that the user interacts with. We could see no way to make an Ionic app run as a Cloud Function. And without Cloud Functions, the "__session" cookie set by the GAE backend apparently gets stripped by the browser client running the app, along with all other cookies.
- Adding "Access-Control-Allow-Origin/-Credentials/-Methods/-Headers" headers to the GAE-code generated response, and setting `crossDomain: true xhrFields: { withCredentials: true }` on the client side, does not improve the situation. Still, no cookie from the GAE code gets set on the browser.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Okay, maybe I am thinking in the wrong direction, but if I'm not, it might help you. I wonder if the backend server allows cross-domain cookies. Localhost is often allowed by exception, but since your app now is running on xxx.firebaseapp.com, the requests are coming from a different domain. [An answer like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14472492) might point you in the right direction. Overall I think it's more likely that the problem resides on the GAE-end than on the Firebase-end.

Comment: Did you test in different browsers and got the same result?

Comment: @Wouter Here it is weeks later and we still don't have a solution. But I'd like to address your comment in case it triggers any additional ideas: First, the backend server (that is, the GAE server) works with the "ionic serve" version of the app, which means that it's using the Chrome browser on the development machine (just like "firebase serve" does) but with some mysterious ionic infrastructure in the code running on the browser not in place with "firebase serve". The fact that it works for "ionic serve" tells us that GAE can set and get cookies if the browser code allows it...

Comment: .... The problem is also not the URL name, since both "ionic serve" (which works) and "firebase serve" (which doesn't work) run from localhost on the Chrome browser. But we agree that Firebase doesn't really seem to be involved in the actual transaction, which takes place between the browser and GAE. Firebase just acted as the server for the browser code.

Comment: @tiagoperes Yes. Same problem occurs with Safari.