# How to use Auth::check or Auth::user between different domains?

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-5, cors

I've got a question regarding Laravel framework (vers. 5.2) and the authentication. I have 2 domains which represent a software. let's call them `https://azure.mydomain.com` and `https://azuresoftware.mydomain.com`.

The Laravel application is hosted on the domain `https://azuresoftware.mydomain.com`. `https://azure.mydomain.com` is just a CMS framework which is providing some information about the website.

Now I want to display different menus, if the user is logged in or not on `https://azure.mydomain.com`. I thought, I can do a `fetch` request to `https://azuresoftware.mydomain.com/` and use the Laravel methods `Auth::check()` to check if the user is already logged in or not. I know that this is a CORS fetch request, but this is not the issue. I've allowed in the IIS webserver requests from `https://azure.mydomain.com`. The request works fine and also just a simple request. But actually `Auth::check()` is always returning `false`, even when I'm logged in on the software side.

This is my code so far:

```
<script>
    fetch('https://azuresoftware.mydomain.com/checkLogin', {
        method: 'GET', 
        headers: { 
            'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
        }
    })
    .then(function(res) { 
        return res.json()
    })
    .then(function(data) { 
        if(data.isLoggedIn) {
            // do some stuff...
        }
        else 
        {
            // do some other stuff...   
        }
    });
</script>
```

**routes.php:**

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {
...
    Route::get('checkLogin', function() {
        return json_encode(['isLoggedIn'=>\Auth::check()]);
    });
...
```

I'm sure, I forgot something essential, why it is not working this way.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the fact that AJAX calls only send cookies if the url you're calling is on the same domain as your calling script.

See [Cross domain POST request is not sending cookie Ajax Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14462423/cross-domain-post-request-is-not-sending-cookie-ajax-jquery) for more information.