# php Session and cookies not work for jquery .load

Tags: php, jquery, session

i use this code for give normal data(html) from subdomain url;

```
$(document).delegate("#listLastMyUploads",'click',function(){
    $('#files')
    .load('http://accounts.domain.com/test.php');
});
```

but after load file sessions not worked !;

i use this code for set option sessions php , but not worked :

```
session_name("myDomain");
ini_set ("session.cookie_domain", '.domain.com') ;
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.domain.com');
session_start();
```

address **without jquery** (address bar of browser) is very nice working ..

Comment: after open url use jquery load , changed session_id !!!

Comment: AJAX calls only send Cookies if the url you're calling is on the same domain as your calling script. http://stackoverflow.com/a/5422323/215939