# Ajax 'GET' http method behavior

Tags: jquery, ajax, cookies

When i send a HTTP `GET` via ajax, does it includes propers cookies? or cookies goes in the request only when Method is `POST`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A get request should send cookies.

*but*
AJAX calls only send Cookies if the url you're calling is on the same domain as your calling script.

[Read more in this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5422323/3336235)

*notice*
localhost:3000 and localhost:3001 is not the same domain and treated as cross domain, so no cookies will be sent. [(source)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy#Origin_determination_rules)

Comment: Hmm, I think maybe CORS treats that as cross domain... not 100% sure though

Answer (score 0):

It should send cookies with either type of request, just like the browser does when following links or submitting a form.