# PHP: Session variable lost, session id changes (using Ajax)

Tags: php, ajax, session, cookies

I'm new to PHP and am having trouble using session. 
I call a login php-script from javascript using AJAX. There I want to create the session and set a value.

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
session_start();
header('Content-Type: application/json');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

$_SESSION['username'] = "username";

?>
```

I handle the response in javascript and call another php-script again using AJAX. The other file looks like this:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
session_start();
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Content-Type: application/json');

$username = $_SESSION['username'];
?>
```

But username is null. If I request the session ID in both files, the session ID changed. From the first file a Response Cookie containing a PHPSESSID is sent. Do I have to use this id in the AJAX call calling the second script?

Update: As requested the AJAX-Code:

```
function callAjax(url, data, successCB, errorCB) {
    $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'post',
            data: data,
            success: successCB,
            error: errorCB
    });
}
```

Called like:

```
callAjax(GET_TEMPLATES_PHP_URL, {}, onGetTemplateSuccess, onRessourceRetrievalError);
```

I checked the answers in similar SO question, but they did not help.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: check the session cookie settings. e.g. if your session was set for `/foo` subdir, and your ajax code is in `/bar`, then the cookie will not be visible.

Comment: Show us the Ajax/JS. I can't see how this would fail. However, this `$_SESSION['username'] = "username";` should most likely be `$_SESSION['username'] = $username;`

Comment: @JayBlanchard Shouldn't matter. Error reporting doesn't count as output. *Mornin' Ralph*

Comment: @Fred-ii- updated the question with Ajax code.

Comment: Ahhhhh...seems I encountered this before @Fred-ii- but I just tested and you're right. *Mornin' Sam*

Comment: @MarcB Hi session_get_cookie_params returns "/" for path in the first php file. That's alright, isn't it? Even if my phpscripts are in "/" and my javascript file is in "/scripts/".?

Comment: Are you trying it in Wordpress or any other PHP framework?

Comment: @n-dru no, no frameworks.

Comment: You can find help in this thread: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2870371/why-is-jquerys-ajax-method-not-sending-my-session-cookie

Comment: @n-dru thanks for your post. I got it now.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to user n-dru I figured it out. I called the script like "http://myside.com/script.php" from "http://www.myside.com/index.html". Because the 'www' was missing from the script-call it was a call to a different origin. 
So the cookie got lost. I added the www, removed the "Allow Orgin"-stuff from php and now it works.

Thanks everyone!