# Laravel single sign on with subdomains

Tags: single-sign-on, subdomain, laravel-5

How I can implement single sign-on with subdomains on Laravel-5?
I have:

- api.domain.com
- portal.domain.com

I tryed set domain and driver parameters in /config/session:

```
'driver' => 'cookie'
```

or

```
'driver' => 'file'
```

and

```
'domain' => '.domain.com'
```

or

```
'domain' => null
```

It doesn't work anyway. I gets 401 (Unauthorized) anyway. Why?

In controller (it is standard laravel authentication):

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}
```

Comment: So, if i changed auth middleware for api.domain.com from 'auth.basic' to 'auth' (same as to portal.domain.com) it works. How i can use onceBasic auth for api.domain.com and default auth to portal.domain.com? I want to send ajax request from portal.domain.com to api.domain.com (same credentials and same laravel applications)

Comment: Problem with headers when response is AJAX, see details
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2870371/why-is-jquerys-ajax-method-not-sending-my-session-cookie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Laravel 5 subdomains auth: single sign-up throught AJAX and Once Basic through simple HTTP.

If you want have single sign-up between your subdomains (e.g. `api.domain.com` and `portal.domain.com`) on Laravel you must do it:

1. For your api use next filter (e.g. in controller cunstructor):

   `if (!Auth::check())
           $this->middleware('auth.basic.once');`
2. Set your session (`config/session`):

   `'domain' => '.domain.com'`
3. In jQuery.ajax use next parameters:

   `crossdomain: true
   xhrFields: {withCredentials: true}`
4. Headers your response (e.g. in .htaccess) must contain:

   `Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://api.domain.com"
   Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true`

Now you can make AJAX-request from `portal.domain.com` to `api.domain.com` and simple HTTP-request with basic auth to `api.domain.com`