# Sending Cookies across Cross Domain

Tags: jquery, cookies, cross-domain

Objective : To share cookies across domains

Our UI is running in a server 'A' at port P1 and our services is up and running in the same server 'A' at port P2.

```
 UI (Server 'A', Port P1) ----> Services (Server 'A', Port P2)
```

While making rest calls from UI to Services cookies are not sent as a part of request.

I understand that cookies are not getting shared between domains. Tried the approach suggested in [Why is jquery's .ajax() method not sending my session cookie?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2870371/why-is-jquerys-ajax-method-not-sending-my-session-cookie), but to no luck.

```
 $.ajax({
     url: a_cross_domain_url,
     xhrFields: {
     withCredentials: true
      }
    });
```

Planning to try the below approaches, any inputs or thoughts on achieving our objective would be appreciated. Thanks.

Approaches :

1. To set the required cookie in Cookie header attribute as suggested in https://www.drupal.org/node/1133084

   ```
   $.ajax({
    url: a_cross_domain_url,
    xhrFields: {
    withCredentials: true
     },
     //    headers: {'Cookie' : 'cookieName=cookieValue'},
     beforeSend: function(xhr) {
          xhr.setRequestHeader("Cookie", 'cookieName=cookieValue');
     });
   ```
2. To host and access UI and Services using a common VIP (lets say :   https://example.com), in this way browser won't feel the request is made across domains.

   ```
    UI (https://example.com) ----> Services (https://example.com/service1)
   ```

**Update :**

We went ahead  with 2nd approach, as both the applications were getting accessed by a common VIP the cookies were sent across by the browser.

Comment: Good read : http://techblog.constantcontact.com/software-development/using-cors-for-cross-domain-ajax-requests/

Comment: What is common VIP? Please, when you solve problem, be little detailed, because a lot of people will have the same problem like you. You will save it's time, like they can save yours in other hand.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i feel second approach is cleaner.I have tried & it works.