# jQuery cross-domain AJAX request works on one page, but not another

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, cookies

Here's a weird situation I can't figure out.

I'm making a cross-domain AJAX request on my site, from its `http` domain to its `https` one. I'm doing this via buttons on two different pages. On one page, the request works fine, and I can see from Firebug that my session cookies are sent across to the server properly. On the other page - under the same domain and URL structure - no cookies are sent.

E.g. working from http://www.example.com/en/apples
But not working from http://www.example.com/en/oranges

The code is as follows:

```
var ajaxUrl = "https://www.example.com/en/controller/add/bananas/";

jQuery.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: ajaxUrl,
    xhrFields: {
         withCredentials: true
    },
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function(data) {
      console.log("Yay");
    }
  }
);
```

My `https` site responds with:

```
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin      "http://www.example.com"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Credentials "true"
```

I know it works because it works on `/apples` but the exact same code doesn't work on `/oranges`! What's going on here?

Comment: you cant make a `https` request from a `http` page. I doubt even how your first case is working

Comment: There are ways to make http ajax call an https page. First, are you sure the origin headers are the same for `/apples` and `/oranges`? Can you inspect with Chrome or FF please.

Comment: @Drakes The headers are definitely all the same, except for the `Referer` which is different as you'd expect. And the `/oranges` page isn't sending a `Cookie` header with the request (which is the issue).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still not sure why it was working on one page but not another, however I fixed it by adding more headers to the HTTPS server via Apache's conf.d file:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin      "http://www.example.com"
    Header add Access-Control-Allow-Credentials "true"
    Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods     "GET, POST"
    Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers     "Content-Type, Authorization, X-Requested-With"
    Header add Access-Control-Max-Age           "1000"
</IfModule>
```

Both pages now work.

Also check:
• [Why is jquery's .ajax() method not sending my session cookie?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2870371/why-is-jquerys-ajax-method-not-sending-my-session-cookie)
• [How do I send a cross-domain POST request via JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298745/how-do-i-send-a-cross-domain-post-request-via-javascript)