# 401 Unauthorized not interpreted in firefox

Tags: php, ajax, firefox, cakephp-2.5

I am working on `CAKE PHP 2.5.x` and if user session expired then I throw `401 unauthorized` exception in response to `HTTP/AJAX` request.

Now, if I logged out meanwhile and browser sends `AJAX` request to server. So in such case server sends `401` exception.

```
$( document ).ajaxError(function(x,e){
    if(e.status == "401"){
        alert('requested restricted area!');
        window.location.reload();
    }
});
```

From above code, I am handling `401` thrown via `AJAX`. This is working fine in `chrome`.

But I don't know `firefox` is getting response `403 Forbidden` for same scenario and due to this my check for unauthorized fails.

**P.S.** `AJAX` call is on `same domain` and also no authentication for each `AJAX` call. I simply check if user logged or not on server side.

Can you please help me out. Thank you in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29782222/jquery-ajax-call-results-in-401-unauthorized-response-when-in-chrome-or-firefo

Comment: @Deep I am calling AJAX to my same domain only and no authentication parameters required in each request.