# 401 (Unauthorized) in Chrome, but not in IE

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, fetch, redux, unauthorized

I recently moved from using jQuery to using isomorphic-fetch with Redux. When running in IE, it manages to fetch fine. However I get the below when running in Chrome.

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized)
```

It may be worth noting that the web api does have windows authentication enabled.

Here's the code that executes the fetch:

```
export const fetchSearchResults = (name) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(requestSearchResults(name))
    return fetch(API URI HERE)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => {
        console.log('Fetch: ' + json.message.features.length)
        dispatch(receiveSearchResults(json))
      })
  }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29782222/jquery-ajax-call-results-in-401-unauthorized-response-when-in-chrome-or-firefo

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @CanÜrek My question relates to isomorphic-fetch, jQuery works fine cross-browser.

Comment: This question feels well-worded to me, FWIW. And the accepted answer appears to work, for the reasons the answerer describes.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I suppose you have cookie-based authentication on server. In this case it could be related to `credentials` key for `fetch`. XHR requests, that used in jQuery *always* send your cookie, but using `fetch` you should pass `credentials` option with

- `same-origin` if you make request to the same origin (domain)
- `include` otherwise

Like this:

```
...
fetch(API_URI_HERE, {credentials: 'same-origin'})
...
```

I assume that it works in IE because `fetch` polyfill uses XHR requests under the hood.

Comment: I'll give this a shot, but this looks exactly like the problem. Thank you!