# Send a session token via AJAX

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Is there a way to get the rails session cookie from the client via `Java Script` and then send it over an `AJAX` request to prove identity?

I'm trying to implement an edit to a rails model via `Javascript` and `JQuery`. I'm concerned about malicious users sending post requests to the rails app and editing models so I want to check the `current_user` stored in the rails session. Is it possible to send this session over `AJAX` and use it on the rails side?

Comment: Cookies should already be sent in AJAX requests, unless the AJAX request is calling a different domain?

Comment: @Stryner looks like you're right! Thanks. Do you want to post an answer?

Comment: Not really since I just googled and regurgitated what I found at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2870371/why-is-jquerys-ajax-method-not-sending-my-session-cookie. I would feel dirty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems `Rails` actually handles this for you.

Answer (score 1):

**You can get the CRFS token and put as a header:**

JQuery

```
var token = $( 'meta[name="csrf-token"]' ).attr( 'content' );

$.ajaxSetup( {
  beforeSend: function ( xhr ) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader( 'X-CSRF-Token', token );
  }
});
```

**Hope this helps!**